# Convert UTF-8 to base64 string

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, base64

I'm trying to convert `UTF-8` to `base64` string.

Example: I have "abcdef==" in `UTF-8`. It's in fact a "representation" of a `base64` string.

How can I retrieve a "abcdef==" `base64` string (note that I don't want a "abcdef==" "translation" from `UTF-8`, I want to get a string encoded in `base64` which **is** "abcdef==").

**EDIT**
As my question seems to be unclear, here is a reformulation:

My byte array (let's say I name it A) is represented by a `base64` string. Converting A to `base64` gives me "abcdef==".

This string representation is sent through a socket in UTF-8 (note that the string representation is exactly the same in UTF-8 and base64). So I receive an UTF-8 message which contains "whatever/abcdef==/whatever" in UTF-8.

So I need to retrieve the base64 "abcedf==" string from this socket message in order to get A.

I hope this is more clear!

Answer (score 148, accepted):

It's a little difficult to tell what you're trying to achieve, but assuming you're trying to get a Base64 string that when *decoded* is `abcdef==`, the following should work:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abcdef==");
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(base64);
```

This will output: `YWJjZGVmPT0=` which is `abcdef==` encoded in Base64.

**Edit:**

To decode a Base64 string, simply use `Convert.FromBase64String()`. E.g.

```
string base64 = "YWJjZGVmPT0=";
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

At this point, `bytes` will be a `byte[]` (not a `string`). If we know that the byte array represents a string in UTF8, then it can be converted back to the string form using:

```
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

This will output the original input string, `abcdef==` in this case.

Comment: I want the opposite : "This will output: "abcdef==" which is "XXXX" encoded in Base64.". I will update my post

Comment: Or if I do that, how do I find UTF-8 `YWJjZGVmPT0=` from UTF-8 `abcdef==`?

Comment: Simple as that. Thanks a lot

Comment: @NicolasVoron I have updated my answer to provide the inverse operation as well.

Comment: I saw that and I've marked your answer as the rihgt one. I was searching for so-complicated solutions... Once again thanks a lot :)