# Neo4j: No Authentication header supplied for db/data

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to access the rest api of my local Neo4j instance. I have read the docs which state that in order to log in you must supply an Authorization header such as the following:

`Authorization: Basic {base64 string}`

This works perfectly for `GET http://localhost/user/neo4j` as expected, but it fails with the following message for `GET http://localhost/db/data`:

`{"errors": [{
   "code": "Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized",
   "message": "No authentication header supplied."
}]}`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

neo4j 3.6 on Mac OSX Sierra

Comment: What version of Neo4j? Are you wanting to send Cypher? Does it work with the [Cypher transactional endpoint](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/#http-api-transactional), `POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit` ?

Comment: Thanks for asking - I've added the version to the question. All I am trying to do is to get a JSON response from the root, I am no further forward than that. I am trying to develop my understanding by working through the examples in the manual.

Comment: Yes, it works with the Cypher transactional endpoint

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same problem and kicked myself when I eventually discovered the problem.

You need the trailing `/` try  using the url `http://localhost/db/data/`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I found this on SO a while ago, but can't find it anymore.  First, a little clarification.  Neo4j is looking for a base64 encoded string with the syntax "username:password".

To get that use this [Convert UTF-8 to base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938137/convert-utf-8-to-base64-string) reference

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("foo:pwd");
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(base64);
```

(Note: I'm using Postman). Now that you have a properly formatted base64 string, add this to your header:
Authorization Basic

[screencap of Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwaQZ.png)

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, but I think you've misread my question; I'm already including those headers.

Comment: This may be a config file issue.  see if this works `http://username:password@localhost:7474`

Comment: I was getting this error in Neo4j Browser, I have to hit the same query multiple times until suddenly / randomly it runs without error