# Encrypt string in ASP decrypt in Java

Tags: java, encryption, vbscript, asp-classic

I have below ASP code to encrypt and decrypt in asp. It works fine. I want string to be encrypted in asp and decrypt it in java.

```
set obj=Server.CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged")
Set endocde = Server.CreateObject("System.Text.endocdeEncoding")

un = endocde.GetBytes_4("Test Encryption")                                      
obj.key = endocde.GetBytes_4("SomeRandomKey")                       
obj.iv =  endocde.GetBytes_4("SomeRandomIv")    

set enc=obj.CreateEncryptor()   
uncUn=enc.TransformFinalBlock((un),0,lenb(un))          
eUn=endocde.GetString((uncUn))      

set dec=obj.CreateDecryptor()
byted=dec.TransformFinalBlock((uncUn),0,lenb(uncUn))
sd=endocde.GetString((byted))
```

I tried encrypted string to be decrypted using below code in java but doesnt work. I tried sending encrypted data in UTF8/Base64 but doesnt work. Please help.

```
String iv = "sameIVasASP";
String key = "sameKeyasASP";

IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes("UTF-8"));
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Rijndael");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Rijndael/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");    
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);             
byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(<encrpted string>);              
System.out.println( new String(cipher.doFinal(decode)).getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

How to encode/decode UTF-8 string to base64 in [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938137/convert-utf-8-to-base64-string):

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("string-to-encode");
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

How to encode/decode UTF-8 string to base64 in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java)

Java8 version:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64encodedstring);
```

Pre-Java8 example (with Base64 class of Commons Codec):

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedBytes);
```

(In Java you have many option to do that (not just these), if you are using at least Java8, there is a built in [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) for that, for previous versions I usually use [the Base64 class in Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.11/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html))